# Trying to find a file named iofputs.c when running application that i made in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb

I am trying to write application for converting using lame library in Ubuntu 14.04 and succeed in compiling and linking 
I saw after running application like segment fault and made in core.dump file

- debug 1

debug 
I Nemiver(gdb wrapper) with core file and execution file in each. 
I saw this below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnjGa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5TAp.png)

I looked into lib directory, There is no eglibc directory???

- debug 2

An Application that i wrote is the almost the same as lame in fronted directory in lame(lame-3.99.5.tar.gz),but an execution file of lame has no eror even though barrow the code into my application 
What is different between lame and my apppication 
I debugged ldd applicaiton but nothing special
I added the option of gcc with "-save-temps" to know Is there file calling iofputs.c but   be not existed..
 this is intermediate file having error

```
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitflags.h" 1 3 4
# 50 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitflags.h" 3 4
typedef enum
{
  P_ALL,
  P_PID,
  P_PGID
} idtype_t;
# 42 "/usr/include/stdlib.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h" 1 3 4
# 64 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/waitstatus.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/endian.h" 1 3 4
# 36 "/usr/include/endian.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/endian.h" 1 3 4
# 37 "/usr/include/endian.h" 2 3 4
# 60 "/usr/include/endian.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h" 2 3 4
.....

extern int fputs (const char *__restrict __s, FILE *__restrict __stream);
```

- debug 3

This compilation command that i ran

```
gcc parse.c brhist.c lametime.c get_audio.c timestatus.c Candidate.c console.c -ggdb -lmp3lame -I ../../include/ -I ../../ -I ../../frontend/ -I ../../libmp3lame -m64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  **-lncurses** -o candidate -Wall -pipe
```

this upper is having issue because of, as i thought, using system library of lame so that i changed to use the library what i compiled of lame labrary

```
**libtool --tag=gcc --mode=link** gcc  parse.c brhist.c lametime.c get_audio.c timestatus.c Candidate.c console.c -ggdb **../lib/libmp3lame.la** -save-temps -I ../../include/ -I ../../ -I ../../frontend/ -I ../../libmp3lame -m64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -lncurses -o candidate
```

Unfortunately the result is the same for finding iofputs.c

Would you help me out ?
I don't have an idea to solve it out.....

Answer (score 0):

> Would you help me out. I don't have an idea to solve it

The file you are trying to find is part of EGLIBC build, which is performed in a temporary directory. You will not find that file in this location. But you can find it in GLIBC source, e.g. [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofputs.c;h=4868ce40d9371c69892b15a9538371f954f9ae4a;hb=HEAD).

The command you *really* want GDB to execute is `where` -- that will show you the crash stack trace, and parameters.

It seems likely that you invoked `fputs` or `fprintf` with a `NULL` value of `fp`, which often happens when you don't check the result of earlier `fopen` call for errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ^^ I will check this out

Comment: Thanks for  your helping me out, I get it, solved after missing open function is inserted.